# How can I delete the default display string "(Collection)" in a PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, collections, graphics, propertygrid

my goal is to replace the display value of a PropertyGrid property trough an own UITypeEditor.
But I'm not able to delete the default display string "(Collection)" that is always shown.

[image: I want to remove the "(Collection)" string]

I tried e.Graphics.Clear and drawing with a white brush into the graphics. But that's not working. Here's my code:

```
public class MyUITypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override void PaintValue(PaintValueEventArgs e)
    {
        // Not working:
        //e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        //using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
        //{
        //    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
        //}

        e.Graphics.DrawString(
            "0|0, 10|10",
            new Font("Arial", 10f, FontStyle.Bold),
            new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
            new Point(0, 0));
    }

    public override bool GetPaintValueSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to define a new `TypeConverter` element and override the methods below:

```
public class test_typeconverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture,
    object value, Type destinationType)
            => "Text requiered";

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) => true;

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) => false;
}
```

Then, you have to define this type as the type converter of the collection you want to show in the property grid as below:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(test_typeconverter))]
public List<int> Values { get; set; }
```

[image: Result of the code]

Comment: Was this usefull for you?

Comment: Yeah exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much <3